# Change in Work flow state disables Workflow command in Quick actions or gutter panel

Tags: workflow

Changing the work flow state moves the item to next state but disables Work flow commands in the Quick actions panel. However, it is enabled in the Ribbon (Review tab)

[image]

Screenshot from the gutter

[image]

But, Gutter panel shows the commands enabled when logged-in as administrator

Comment: Does the user has read access on the path where the workflow is stored? Example: `/sitecore/system/Workflows/Standard Workflow`

Comment: Yes. Access Viewer shows the user has access to Work Flow execute

Answer (score 1):

As of Sitecore 8.1 Update-3, users are required to first Lock an item before changing its workflow state.

See [Sitecore 8.1 Update-3 (rev. 160519) Release Notes](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Sitecore%2081/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2081%20Update3/Release%20Notes) the reference number is 96708

> 96708, 450554: Users must now lock an item to change its workflow state.